# How can others run my SFML/C++ projects without Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sfml

I've built this SFML project that is only one C++ file. It works fine with my computer, with or without Visual Studio. I selected the release x86 option, and then compressed the release folder and sent it to my friends who couldn't run it. They got an error that said, "The program couldn't start because MSVCP140.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program." What do I do to fix this? I'm sry if it's a newby question.
Thx for any future help! =]

Comment: You can create an installer that not only installs your .exe, but also installs the needed dlls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a well known problem, and thankfully it has a well known solution.

Your friends just need to download and install the Visual Studio 2015 redistributable package here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145

Since you said your program was built for x86 (32-bit), then make sure they download the corresponding x86 redistributable.  If you decide to build it for x64 (64-bit), which I recommend, then make sure they download the corresponding x64 redistributable.

If you were to ever get to the point of putting together an installer for your program, then it would be highly recommended to bundle it with the Visual Studio 2015 redistributable package (as mentioned by Trevor Hickey in comments).

**Oh, but why?**

When your program is compiled and linked by Visual Studio, it is utilizing a version of the C++ standard library created for and used by the same version of Visual Studio (2015 in your case, which I can tell by the required DLL name MSVCP**140**.dll).  Since vanilla Windows does not ship with this library, it is a crapshoot as to whether any computer has it, because it may or may not have already been installed by some other program that needed it.